# DASL to filter mails received in a specific day

Tags: vba, datetime, outlook, filtering

I would like to use a DASL filter to filter mails received in a specific day.

```vb
filterstring = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%" & subject & "%'" & _
  " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" LIKE '%" & received_date & "%'" & _
  " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" LIKE '%" & received_date_plus & "%'"
```

The variables are previously defined. "received_date_plus" is the received date plus one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator is used for string properties. You need to use `<` and `>` to compare date time values (and never use equality operators). Read more about that in the [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) article.

```
filterstring = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%" & subject & "%'" & _
    " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" > '" & Format(received_date ,"General Date")& "' & _
    " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" < '" & Format(received_date_plus, "General Date")  & "'"
```

Pay attention to the fact that dates should be formatted like Outlook expects them. So, it makes sense to use the `Format` function available in VBA.

Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Comment: yes indeed! I forgot to replace the LIKE operator in case of the date filters and after that I changed my code to: 

filterstring = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" LIKE '%" & subject & "%'" & _
        " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '%" & received_date & "%'" & _
        " AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" <= '%" & received_date_plus & "%'"

it worked , thank you! :)